# MVC authentication and authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I am using MVC 4 and am using Forms authentication.  I have heard that MVC has it's own implementation of authentication and authorization but am not sure what it is and how to use it.  What is MVC's implementation called and is it easy to migrate from forms to use it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is.  Sort of.

MVC (versions 1-3) used standard Membership databsaes and Forms Authentication.  MVC 4 uses standard Forms Authentication as well, but uses a system called WebSecurity to access it's membership system.  WebSecurity was created for the WebMatrix project and MVC 4 has adopted it's use in the default templates.

You can still use the standard Membership system if you want, however WebSecurity (and in particular SimpleMembership) allows greater customization of the data.

MVC also can be configured in several ways for authorization.  You can use the older web.config method, or you can use AuthorizationFilters such as the `[Authorize]` attribute.  This still uses FormsAuthentication, however under the covers, it's just a way to configure the use of it.